# Get BillingAgreementID from TransactionID

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible to get BillingAgreementID from completed recurring/reference transaction id?

I got situation when my customer accepted billing agreement and completed transaction, but BillingAgreementID was not collected at my side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't so its possible as I tried myself to call the GetTransactionDetails API on a existing Transaction Id which was done using the Billing agreement but didn't get the billing agreemnt Id in response . Below is my response :

```
NVP Response:
RECEIVERBUSINESS=XXXXXXXX
RECEIVEREMAIL=XXXXXXXXX
RECEIVERID=XXXXXXXX
EMAIL=XXXXXXXX
PAYERID=XXXXXXXXX
PAYERSTATUS=verified
COUNTRYCODE=US
ADDRESSOWNER=PayPal
ADDRESSSTATUS=None
SALESTAX=0.00
SHIPAMOUNT=0.00
SHIPHANDLEAMOUNT=0.00
TIMESTAMP=2014-09-11T21:20:46Z
CORRELATIONID=47f3e5bd2249
ACK=Success
VERSION=109.0
BUILD=12786467
FIRSTNAME=Eshan Personal Test
LASTNAME=Account
TRANSACTIONID=5YL30211NW355272S
TRANSACTIONTYPE=merchtpmt
PAYMENTTYPE=instant
ORDERTIME=2014-09-11T20:49:58Z
AMT=10.00
FEEAMT=0.59
TAXAMT=0.00
CURRENCYCODE=USD
PAYMENTSTATUS=Completed
PENDINGREASON=None
REASONCODE=None
PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY=Ineligible
PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE=None
L_QTY0=1
L_TAXAMT0=0.00
L_CURRENCYCODE0=USD
L_TAXABLE0=false
```

The only thing that you can do is to get the billing agreement id from your PayPal account by accessing your recurring Payments dashboard . Or you can directly go to this link :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_merchant-hub